# How do I store some images in folder A and some images in folder B when they are published?

Tags: content-delivery, storage-extensions

Currently we are storing images(documents) on the server(\serverName\content\published_images) as a default file system.

As part of the requirement, I need to store some images in folder A and some images in folder B. Could you please help me the to achieve this requirement? Which configuration files needs to be updated.

Comment: duplicate; http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/863/publishing-binaries-to-2-different-paths-possible or http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/publish-multimedia-to-sub-folder-with-dynamic-component-template

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to use the addbinary method of the TOM.NET api as described in the comments, but it's also possible to edit your storage configuration to store different file types in different storages.  Actually there's a lot you can do with storage (cd_storage_conf.xml) so id recommend reading the docs to see what's possible.

this might mean you don't need to do any actual code updates to store your binaries in a suitable format.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of issues you have to use two deployers. As you know, there could be the various options for this, but seems the simplest is just running two upload sites with different configurations.

or

You need to create 2 different storage for different and provide storage id in your publication configuration for different type of binaries.

```
<Publication Id="111" cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb" >
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="storageLocation1" cached="true"/>
        <Item typeMapping="Binary" storageId="storageLocation2" cached="true"/>
</Publication>
```

or

The other way would be your's Tbb code, through which you can achieve any kind of requirement but for this way you need to write code.